# example of a sequence of points in $l_1$ with sup metric that converges to a point in $l_\infty$ where that point is not in $l_1$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, metric-spaces

I just can't see an example that would fit this description.

Wouldn't it mean that the space is closed as well?

Comment: Can you precise your metric in $\ell^1$?

Comment: i didn't get $l_1$ with sup norm part. can you be more precise?

Comment: L1 metric is the absolutely value convergence

Comment: A sequence of points in l1 that converged in (linfinity,dinfinity) to a point in linfinity(bounded) but where that point is not in l1?

Comment: Consider the sequence $x_n= (1,1/2,\dots , 1/n,0,0,\dots ).$

Answer (score 2):

take the sequence

$x_n=(1,1/2,....,1/n,0,0.....)$

then it doesn't converge in $l_1$ as $\sum (1/n)$ is not finite

but it converges in $l_\infty$ to $(1/n)_{n\geqslant1}^{\infty}$